# How do I upgrade Lubuntu 14.04.03 LTS to the current official none-LTS Lubuntu?

Tags: upgrade

How do I upgrade Lubuntu 14.04.03 LTS to the current official none-LTS Lubuntu?

I found texts about `update-manager` and `do-release-upgrade`. Which one should I use?

I tried an update but then `/sbin/init` is missing and the kernel give me a `panic` while booting.
So I want to be sure to use the correct upgrade mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't.

Upgrades can happen only from one supported version to the immediate next supported version. In your case, 14.10 isn't supported any longer. Its support terminated on [July 23 2015](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29).

If you wish to be on 15.10, the latest, non-LTS version, you need to do a clean install of 15.10 (after backing up your data).

Comment: No, you can upgrade to 15.10 in Ubuntu LTS releases...

Comment: @IAnsari: I tested that. It is definitly not possible. The upgrader works but after that the system is un-bootable.

Comment: @buhtz ??? Worked for me...

Answer (score 3):

You CAN upgrade to Lubuntu/Ubuntu 15.10. See the steps below to upgrade from 14.04 to 15.10.

1. Open "Software & Updates" in the Menu.
2. Select the "Updates" tab.
3. Select the drop-down box next to "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version:"
4. Select "For any new version" from the list displayed.
5. Close the window and open "Software Updater".
6. Let it check for updates and it will notify you about the new Lubuntu/Ubuntu 15.04 release.
7. Upgrade to the newer version!

Answer (score 1):

Found this question today. I was on Lubuntu 14.04 and updated to 18.04, so the accepted answer is incorrect. Here are my steps (sorry I am very new to Lubuntu and created an account, I hope this helps)

1. I clicked on the start button>System tools>software updater. I updated the software.
2. Rebooted
3. I clicked on the start button>System tools>software updater then ran the updater again it said my software was updated, but it asked me if I wanted to update to 16.04 I said yes.
4. Now I am on 16.04 I clicked on the start button>System tools>software updater I updated the partial update. (maybe optional)
5. I clicked on the start button>System tools>software updater it said my software was updated, but it asked me if I wanted to update to 18.04 I said yes. I am now at 18.04.

Comment: The question was about going from 14.04, that was an LTS version, to the "current none-LTS" version i.e 19.04 currently. You went to 16.04 and 18.04 that are LTS versions. So, unless you find a way to upgrade to 19.04 (or 18.10) from your 18.04, the accepted answer is definitely correct ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can update it.use Start>System Tools>Software Updater in the GUI.